# There is no link or button to my blog page

Tags: blog-page

I have a blog page and Ive done a blog, but the only way other people can get to it is if they add /blog to the home page eg https://www.botanicalhome.com.au/pages/blog/

I dont want my home page to be my blog, but id like a link to it or a way nice section on my home page where it can be seen. Say at the bottom. Ive gone into appearance but cant seem to figure it out.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Custom Link to your Menu. Give it the title "Blog" and just enter your blog URL as the link. That would probably be the quickest solution.

[image: Depiction of the Custom Links box]